# Curve Fitting scipy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

why this fitting is this much bad ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin(b * x + c) + d

xdata = np.linspace(0, 360, 1000)
ydata = 89.9535 + 60.9535 * np.sin(0.0174 * xdata - 1.5708)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit, xdata, ydata)

plt.plot(xdata, 89.9535 + 60.9535 * np.sin(0.0174 * xdata - 1.5708))
plt.plot(xdata, fit(xdata, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]))
plt.show()
```

the fitted curve seems very strange, or maybe I am miss using it , thanks for any helps .

This is the result:

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 0):

`curve_fit` finds a *local* minimum for the least-squares problem.  In this case, there are *many* local minima.

One way around this is to use as good an initial guess as possible.  For problems with multiple local minima, `curve_fit`'s default of all ones for the initial guess can be pretty bad.  For your function, the crucial parameter is `b`, the frequency.  If you know that value will be small, i.e. on the order of 0.01, use 0.01 as the initial guess:

```
In [77]: (a, b, c, d), pcov = curve_fit(fit, xdata, ydata, p0=[1, .01, 1, 1])

In [78]: a
Out[78]: 60.953499999999998

In [79]: b
Out[79]: 0.017399999999999999

In [80]: c
Out[80]: -102.10176491487339

In [81]: ((c + np.pi) % (2*np.pi)) - np.pi
Out[81]: -1.570800000000002

In [82]: d
Out[82]: 89.953500000000005
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, plot the original data alone and use it to make initial guesses of the parameters. For a periodic function it can be easy to estimate the period and the amplitude. In this case the guesses need not be too close.

Then I used these in **curve_fit**:

`popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit, xdata, ydata, [ 80., np.pi/330, 1., 1. ])`

The result it returned are essentially the original values.

```
array([  6.09535000e+01,   1.74000000e-02,  -1.57080000e+00,
         8.99535000e+01])
```